# When I install pydensecrf I have an error

Tags: python-3.x

I tried put this line

```
$ pip install cython
```

but, I have an error like this

```
I/home/jsim/Desktop/Weakly_Segmentation/PuzzleCAM/PuzzleCamVenv/include/python3.8 -c pydensecrf/eigen.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/pydensecrf/eigen.o
    pydensecrf/eigen.cpp:23:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/jsim/Desktop/Weakly_Segmentation/PuzzleCAM/PuzzleCamVenv/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vyhjigzc/pydensecrf_a00996eb1c2a4603a91b34051c1c43aa/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vyhjigzc/pydensecrf_a00996eb1c2a4603a91b34051c1c43aa/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hyknmek_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jsim/Desktop/Weakly_Segmentation/PuzzleCAM/PuzzleCamVenv/include/site/python3.8/pydensecrf Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev


pip install git+https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/pydensecrf.git
```

but, the problem is not solved.

How to solve this problem??
Please Help ME!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
pip install cython
```

then

```
pip install git+https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/pydensecrf.git
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, downgrading Cython to 0.29.36 worked.

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall cython==0.29.36
```

and then,

```
pip3 install --no-build-isolation git+https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/pydensecrf.git
```

refer to [This Github Link](https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/pydensecrf/issues/123)